# PyCharm does not import Scapy module

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying and failing to import scapy into python, which I have now been playing with for hours and all the google hits I get seem to make sense but when I try them - it fails.

first off I am using python3 and have that nicely in pycharm:

[Correct Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1utO.png)

I have also installed the package using pip3:

```
pip3 install scapy-python3
```

this appears in PyCharm as you can see in the picture. So I am now on a par with the other guides I found.

So finally I try:

```
from scapy import *
```

and for good measure

```
from scapy.all import *
```

which is for Python2 and 3k from what I read.

Could someone give me a hand, I don't know where to go next.

Gareth

Comment: how does it fails ? what are the error messages you're facing ?

Comment: After a reload it works fine. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scapy-python3 is a different and outdated project.

The correct way to install scapy on python 3 is

```
pip3 install scapy
```

Or

```
python3 -m pip install scapy
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is better to install scapy package for python2, too; by following command:

```
pip install scapy
```

try this.

Comment: How would python2 affect python3? I thought they were completely separate?

Comment: yes, you are right they are completely separate. But it is a personal experience, I have used VScode and it uses python2 as debuger by default. So maybe it works for you.